# Subsetting within two differing but dependent MATLAB arrays/matrices

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, subset

I have two matrices containing cartesian coordinates:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(1:100,1:100);
plot(x,y,'o')
```

I wish to subset these matrices in such a way that I remove a rectangular subset of these coordinates. I'm unsure how to best specify where the subset will be taken from. Let's assume the bounding box of the rectangle will be `rect = [30 40 50 60];`, formatted `[left top right bottom]`.

I've tried subsetting each of the matrices separately, but this removes more of the coordinates than I'd like, and does not give the resulting rectangular 'hole' that I'm looking for :

```
ax = x(x<30 | x>50);
ay = y(y<40 | y>60);
plot(ax,ay,'o')
```

I believe this is because the x and y coordinates contained within the matrices are linked and I need to treat them as a set. I've tried to do this:

```
lx = x(:);
ly = y(:);
coords = horzcat(lx,ly);
```

When I try to subset, I can't get my `x` and `y` coordinates back:

```
[cutout.x, cutout.y] = coords((coords(:,1)<30 & coords(:,2)<40) | (coords(:,1)>50 & coords(:,2)>60));
Indexing cannot yield multiple results.
```

Anything I do get, again, isn't what I'm wanting:

```
cutout = coords((coords(:,1)<30 & coords(:,2)<40) | (coords(:,1)>50 & coords(:,2)>60));
```

How can I subset these two linked MATLAB arrays and get the result I'm looking for?

EDIT: I got a little closer with the `setdiff` function, but still not quite it.

```
cutout = [30:50;40:60]';
result = setdiff(coords,cutout,'rows');
plot(result(:,1), result(:,2), 'o')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mask to set those inside the bounding box as `NaNs` for both `x` and `y` and those points won't show up in the plot -

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(1:100,1:100);

mask = x>=30 & x<=50 & y>=40 & y<=60

x(mask) = nan;
y(mask) = nan;

plot(x,y,'o')
```

Output -

[image]

Hoping this is what you were after!

Comment: It absolutely was, much thanks! I've seen masking used before in this way -- are you able to elaborate upon how it is able to subset while considering the relationship between two or more matrices or arrays?

Comment: @luser Well `x>=30 & x<=50 & y>=40 & y<=60` basically is your bounding box, right? I mean that's pretty obvious, I would think. So, the only thing needed was to get a logical array of ones where the bounding box exists and zeros elsewhere. Then, we index into both `x` and `y` to set the ones-positions to `NaNs`, as nans in a plot don't show up. So, that's the whole thing really about this solution. Makes sense I hope? :)